# Validating issue: Unknown Tag/Undefined attribute name warnings in Eclipe

Tags: eclipse, html, validation, jsp, svg

The following code presents validation issues for me in Eclipse 4.4.2. This is located in a JSP file.

```
       <svg version="1.1" class="..." xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="..." y="..." width="..x" height="..." viewBox="..."
        enable-background="..." xml:space="...">
        <g>
          <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="..."></polygon>
          <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="..."></polygon>
        </g>
       </svg>
```

This code produces the following warnings:

- "Undefined attribute name (attribute-name)" for every attribute attached to the svg element
- "Unknown tag (tag-name)" for the g and polygon tags.

I ran this through an online validator that supports HTML5/SVG1.1, and it told me there were 0 validation issues.
Any ideas why this could be happening? I'm aware that I can choose to ignore the validation issues through Window > Preferences > Validation, but I would prefer to find a way to get Eclipse to actually recognize these tags/attributes because they work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace `http://www.w3.org/2000/svg` does not seem to be recognised by your eclipse installation. Try either of:

- Adding the namespace to your XML catalog (in Window > Preferences), including the schema for svg, or
- Specifying the schema inline, as attributes of the svg element:

  `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-SVG11-20020108/SVG.xsd"`
  (or wherever your local copy of the schema is)